# An item with the same key has already been added - AJAX - jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i am trying to delete a record from list of records. it was working fine before. now when i press delete in ajax function it throws an exception "An item with the same key has already been added."

i have tried some options from already asked and answered questions on this topic but i am unable to solve my problem. i am not able to find out where in my code is any duplicate name or any other duplicate entity/variable.

HTML

```
 <td>
    <div class="hidden-phone visible-desktop btn-group">
        <a href="@Url.Content("~/backend/Car/UpdateUsedCar/")@CryptoProvider.Encrypt(Car.Id)" class="btn btn-mini btn-info" title="Edit Car"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a>
        @*<a href="@Url.Content("~/backend/Car/UsedCarDetails/")@CryptoProvider.Encrypt(Car.Id)" class="btn btn-mini btn-info" title="Details Car"><i class="icon-play"></i></a>*@
        <a href="@Url.Content("~/backend/Car/DeleteUsed/")@CryptoProvider.Encrypt(Car.Id)" onclick='javascript:return deleteConfirmation(this);' class='btn btn-mini btn-danger' title="Delete Car"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>
        <a class="invisible" href="@Url.Content("~/backend/Car/DisableCar/")@CryptoProvider.Encrypt(Car.Id)" onclick='javascript:return deleteConfirmation(this);' class='btn btn-mini btn-danger' title="Restore Car"><i class="icon-ok"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-desktop visible-phone">
        <div class="inline position-relative">
            <button class="btn btn-minier btn-yellow dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-caret-down icon-only"></i></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-icon-only dropdown-yellow pull-right dropdown-caret dropdown-close">
                <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/backend/Car/UpdateUsedCar/")@CryptoProvider.Encrypt(Car.Id)" class="tooltip-success" data-rel="tooltip" title="Edit Car" data-placement="left"><span class="green"><i class="icon-edit"></i></span></a></li>
                @*<li><a href="@Url.Content("~/backend/Car/UsedCarDetails/")@CryptoProvider.Encrypt(Car.Id)" class="tooltip-success" data-rel="tooltip" title="Details Car" data-placement="left"><span class="green"><i class="icon-play"></i></span></a></li>*@
                <li><a href="@Url.Content("~/backend/Car/DeleteUsed/")@CryptoProvider.Encrypt(Car.Id)" onclick='javascript:return deleteConfirmation(this);' class='tooltip-error' data-rel="tooltip" title="Delete Car" data-placement="left"><span class="red"><i class="icon-trash"></i></span></a></li>
                <li class="invisible"><a href="@Url.Content("~/backend/Car/DisableCar/")@CryptoProvider.Encrypt(Car.Id)" onclick='javascript:return deleteConfirmation(this);' class='tooltip-error' data-rel="tooltip" title="Restore Car" data-placement="left"><span class="red"><i class="icon-ok"></i></span></a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Jquery Functions to confirm delete

```
function deleteConfirmation(link) {
    debugger;
    var index = $(link).parent().parent().parent().index();

    $('.deleteThisRecord').removeClass('deleteThisRecord'); // Unselect All
    $(link).addClass('deleteThisRecord');

    var message = GetMessageBox(confirmHeading, deleteMessage, true);
    $('#dataConfirmModal').remove();
    $('body').append(message);
    //if (!$('#dataConfirmModal').length) {
    //    $('body').append(message);
    //}
    $('#dataConfirmModal').find('.modal-body').text($(link).attr('data-confirm'));
    $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('onclick', 'javascript:ajaxDeletion(' + index + ');');
    $('#dataConfirmModal').modal({ show: true });
    return false;
}

function ajaxDeletion(pos) {
    debugger;
    //var url = $('tbody').children('tr').eq(pos).find('.icon-trash').parent().attr('href');
    //var ico = $('tbody').children('tr').eq(pos).find('.icon-trash');
    //var tr = $('tbody').children('tr').eq(pos);
    //var row = $(ico).closest('tr');
    var url = $('.deleteThisRecord').attr('href');
    var row = $('.deleteThisRecord').parents('tr').eq(0);
    var nRow = row[0];
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status) {
            debugger;
            if (data.status == 'success') {
                //oTable.fnDeleteRow(pos);
                //var table1 = $('tbody').parent();
                //alert(tabl1);
                //table1.deleteRow(pos);
                //while (table && table.tagName != 'TABLE')
                //    table = table.parentNode;
                //if (!table)
                //    return;
                //table.deleteRow(row.rowIndex);
                oTable.fnDeleteRow(nRow);
                $('#dataConfirmLabel').html(successHeading);
                $('.modal-body').html(data.message);
                VerifyTable();

            } else {
                debugger;
                $('#dataConfirmLabel').html(failedHeading);
                $('.modal-body').html(data.message);
            }

            debugger;
            $('#btnDialogCancel').hide();
            $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('onclick', '');
            $('#dataConfirmOK').attr('onclick', "$('.close').click();");

        },
        error: function (data, status) {
            debugger;
            //console.log(data);
            //alert(" Can't do because: " + error);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Function in Controller

```
 public ActionResult DeleteUsed(KapCarViewModel model)
        {
delete record
}
```

Function to decrypt the Encrypted value from front-end

```
public bool ContainsPrefix(string prefix) {
            try {
                if (_routeData.Values[prefix] == null || !prefix.ToLower().Equals("id") || _id > 0 || Convert.ToString(_routeData.Values["controller"]) == "Home" ) {
                    return false;
                }
                _routeData.Values[prefix] = CryptoProvider.Decrypt(_routeData.Values[prefix].ToString());
                _id = Convert.ToInt32(_routeData.Values[prefix]);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid request found.");
            }
            return false;
        }
```

View Modle to get/set values

```
public class KapCarViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string EncryptedId { get; set; }
    }
```

i need to delete the record after user confirmation "OK" from dialogue box.
but "An item with the same key has already been added." this error is not allowing me to do so. i didn't make this code from scratch but it was working fine previously. suddenly it stopped working. Please guide me in solving this issue.
Note : when this code goes from front-end to decrypt the record Id value. the decryption function then access the view model where it throws the error

Comment: `javascript:` is not necessary in inline event handlers

Comment: If the script used to work, then there must have been some changes on the backend. It is likely not a front-end problem unless you suddenly start sending empty values or such

Comment: @mplungjan : it may be a backend code logic issue. but this code is not taking me to debug mode. it show error before executing the delete logic from controller.